# py calls returning size bigger than resolution

Tags: python, pyautogui

I have monitor resolution 1900x1200 and I need to verify my app size. However, all three calls return 2904x1764. How is it possible if the screen sz is only 1900x1200.

What am I missing here?

```
Appreciate any pointers….
window = pygetwindow.getWindowsWithTitle('My App')[0]
print("Normal size:{}  {} ".format(window.size, window))
window.maximize()
print("Max size:{}  {} ".format(window.size, window))
window.minimize()
logger.info("Min {}, size: {} ".format(window.size, window))
print("pyautogui.size()  %s", pyautogui.size() )
```

Answer (score 0):

May be your system is forcing some DPI mangling to handle font magnification.

There are systems in which this changes what the system reports to applications for screen sizes and gui coordinates in general (e.g. mouse position).

So basically if this is the case the system is outright lying to applications so that them (in theory) will draw things the way the user likes.